# Apple Subscriptions - SKPaymentTransactionObserver: Sandbox Vs Production

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have built our app and tested subscriptions with sandbox and test flight. Everything works like a dream.

We have gone live this morning and the subscriptions fall over. It seems the app isn't sending the receipt to the server for the server to server receipt validation.

I am using the StoreKit delegate method

```
    >     func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

            if let index = transactions.firstIndex(where: { $0.transactionState.status() == "purchased" }) {
                delegate?.didPurchase()
}
```

Like I say this is working fine in a sandbox environment, posting the receipt to our server. The min I move over to production it seems this method isn't being triggered?

Is there anything different about the receipt/transaction object in production and sandbox?
Has anybody run into this issue before and what was your fix?

Comment: Is this all code you execute in `paymentQueue(_:, updatedTransactions:)`?

Comment: No of course not :)

Comment: Discovered the issue, seems to be a delay in the purchase and the server side verification. When we send our receipt to the Apple servers immediately after purchase, the transaction is missing. Thus we need to verify the receipt at a later time

Comment: So you deal with all transactions and not only the first `purchased` one? Because Apple's documentation states: The application should process each transaction by examining the transaction’s transactionState property. Otherwise you will be left with a lot open transactions.

Comment: No all transactions that are in the failed state or completed state are processed correctly. The problem is actually if a user is subscribed and in a trial, deletes the app/subscription and then attempts to purchase a new subscription. The purchase enum isn’t triggered and only the failed enum.

Comment: Interesting, I checked with our app and you are right. Trying to subscribe after reinstalling the app while having an active subscription, leads to an connection error. How meaningful from Apple. Nevertheless, since you are using server validation you should be able to identify the user as already subscribed and then prevent him from buying another subscription, aren't you?